# Clear keyframes from active shapekey using python

Tags: python, keyframes, shape-keys

I need to clear keyframes from the active shapekey using python. I got this far, this is removing the current keyframe on the active shapekey, but got no clue how to remove all of the keyframes.

```
def clear_shape_key_keyframes_selected():

    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    shapekeys = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
    active_shapekey = shapekeys[obj.active_shape_key_index]
    active_shapekey_name = active_shapekey.name
    
    try:
        obj.data.shape_keys.keyframe_delete(f"key_blocks[\"{active_shapekey_name}\"].value")
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Shapekey has no animation data to delete")
```

other things I tried:

This does work, but deletes keyframes on all the shapekeys:

```
def clear_shape_key_keyframes():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    shape_keys = obj.data.shape_keys
    
    key_blocks = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
    active_shapekey = key_blocks[obj.active_shape_key_index]

    shape_keys.animation_data_clear()
```

However, this does not work, and gives me the:

> error "AttributeError: 'ShapeKey' object has no attribute 'animation_data_clear'"

```
def clear_shape_key_keyframes():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    shape_keys = obj.data.shape_keys
    
    key_blocks = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
    active_shapekey = key_blocks[obj.active_shape_key_index]

    active_shapekey.animation_data_clear()
```

Which is really odd since both seem to be shapekey objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the shape keys animation data (from what you have in the first function in your question).

```
# get the data path
data_path = f"key_blocks[\"{active_shapekey_name}\"].value"

# get animation data
animation_data = obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data
# and its curves
curves = animation_data.action.fcurves

# loop over the curves
for curve in curves:
    # find the one that corresponds to the data path
    if curve.data_path == data_path:
        # remove it
        curves.remove(curve)
        break
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This script will automatically remove all keyframes for the actively selected shape key.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
fcurves = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.animation_data.action.fcurves
for fc in fcurves:
    if fc.data_path.rsplit(".", 1)[0] == obj.active_shape_key.path_from_id():
        fcurves.remove(fc)
```

Comment: thanks, working great. appreciate it!